# charts doesnt scale when display is zoomed in

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Ive got an legacy VB/C# WinForms application and have the following scalling problem:

The app is using ChartFx 7 to display some data like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

When I change the display (Windows 7) to 150% I get this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

The charts don’t adapt but the legend does obviously. The form is invoked by the main form of the application. If I set the form as the startup form it works again!

Has anybody an idea whats going wrong here? Is there a setting in the context of the main form which is responsible for that or is it a problem of ChartFx?

Edit: I have just found out its a problem between wpf and winforms: I forgot to mention the application uses winform and wpf. When I remove all wpf calls it scale properly!

Comment: In an MSChart you can manipulare the size (called Position) of each Chartarea. You may want to look out for such a piece of code..

Comment: This may be DPI Issue, you may need to update machine.conf file to make application dpi aware. just google it of dpiaware key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out, setting the dpiAware in the manifest file did it!

```
<asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
        <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
```